# DbContext.Set<TEntity>() in Test Framework Returning Garbage Data Proxies

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

In my Test Framework, when I call `DbContext.Set<FakeClass1>()` I am being returned a whole bunch of garbage data (proxies it seems, as they are `System.Data.Entity.Dynamicproxies`).  If I call `DbContext.FakeClass1s`, I do not get any of this garbage.

The problem is, in a generic Repository bass class I am calling `DbContext.Set<TEntity>()` because obviously it is a nice thing to use to reduce code.  But I need to solve this problem for my Test Framework.

Here is the test code - the result should be a count of 2, because only two have been added to the DbContext DbSet.

```
[TestMethod]
    public void FindAll_Should_Work()
    {
        // Arrange
        var dbContext = new FakeDbContext();

        // Act
        var s1= dbContext.FakeClass1s;
        var s2 = dbContext.Set<FakeClass1>();

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(2, s1.Count());
        Assert.AreEqual(2, s2.Count());
    }
```

The result is correct for `s1`.  But for `s2`, the result is 14.

Here is the code for the FakeDbContext:

```
public class FakeDbContext : System.Data.Entity.DbContext
{
    public DbSet<FakeClass1> FakeClass1s { get; set; }
    public DbSet<FakeClass2> FakeClass2s { get; set; }

    public FakeDbContext()
    {
        PopulateData();
    }

    private void PopulateData()
    {
        var f11 = new FakeClass1()
        {
            ID = 1,
            Name = "One"
        };
        var f12 = new FakeClass1()
        {
            ID = 2,
            Name = "Two"
        };            
        FakeClass1s.Add(f11);
        FakeClass1s.Add(f12);
    }
}
```

Furthermore, these extra results are actually data that seem to have accrued throughout the running of other tests.  In there I find objects with values that come from other tests.  This situation obtains even when I run this test in isolation, and comment out the code where these other objects are being used and tested with.  So something is being remembered.

Also, looking at that locals window it seems `s1` is really a `DbSet<FakeClass1>`, where `s2` is a query (?):

[image]

EDIT: marked the correct answer, but wanted to note here: the issue was inheriting from System.Data.Entity.DbContext.  Obviously, the thing to do is just implement the interface and not derive from this class, as andrerpena kindly suggested.  The strange behavior disappeared once I stopped inheriting from System.Data.Entity.DbContext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are calling garbage are entities that you created in `PopulateData` and that, somehow, got persisted in a database. These `dynamicProxies` are objects of a dynamic type that inherit from `FakeClass1` and `FakeClass2`. The reason why EF creates proxies is so that you can benefit from lazy loading and proper properties synchronization.

Your `FakeDbContext` is inheriting from a real `DbContext`. That causes entities to be actually persisted and retrieved from the store (You have to call SaveChanges so it can happen but you probably are doing that or did in the past). This is not a good practice.

What people normally do is to create an `IDbContext` interface and then create another interface specifically for your context. Something like `IYourAppContext`.

Comment: For clarity, that's the System.Data.Entity.DataContext I'm inheriting from, not one with a connection string in my app, so it's actually not connecting to any real database.  Which makes the persistent 14 entities a real curiosity to me.  But could certainly be something to do with inheriting from System.Entity.DataContext.  I still don't know why that would be, and would certainly like to know the answer.  (And I can see the wisdom in your proposed solution - I would still like to understand what's going on a bit more).